# How to add an extension element in Eclipse Luna (4.4.1)

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp

I would like to know how I can add an extension element for an extension.
In the previous versions, this was possible by right-clicking on an extension and selecting "New" and later one of the predefined elements from the  context menu. But now when I right-click, I don't get anything.

Comment: What extension? where? It is not at all clear what you are asking about.

Comment: plugin.xml -> Extensions

Comment: There has been no change to this

Comment: Any idea why the context menu is not opening when I right-click? I am quite new to Eclipse Plug-in Development by the way. Am I missing something very basic and trivial?

Comment: Which extension point are you working with? Not all extension points have elements.

Comment: For example; "org.eclipse.ui.views". The weird thing is that nothing comes up when I right-click on any extension.

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with my plug-in.

I have resolved it by upgrading to Luna Service Release 2 (4.4.2).

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the RCP targets to make it work. Follow below steps :

- Goto Help
- Install New Software
- type "Update site: http://download.eclipse.org/eclipse/updates/4.4/"
- Choose "Eclipse RCP Target Components" and press Next to install them